# Host Windows 7- Vmbox Ubuntu 14.04 - Network suddenly unreachable

Tags: windows-7, networking, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have trouble reach the host network wiht my Ubuntu VM on my Windows 7 host. It works fine an network suddenly cannot be reached.

alibivmuser@ALIBIVM06:~$ ssh 192.168.0.2
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.2 port 22: Network is unreachable
To exclude any wrong operation from me I just created the VM form scratch but the issue is still there.

Here my VM network configuration:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:4d:20:f5  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:53:89:81  
          inet addr:10.0.3.15  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe53:8981/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:156 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1950 (1.9 KB)  TX bytes:20692 (20.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:169 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:169 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11967 (11.9 KB)  TX bytes:11967 (11.9 KB)
```

And my host network configuration:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Connessione alla rete locale (LAN) 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mynetwork.net
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 139.128.194.212
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 139.128.194.1

Ethernet adapter Connessione alla rete locale (LAN):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.10
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

On my host, Using putty I can properly connect to my target at 192.168.0.2 via ssh. On the VM, I can ping my target at 192.168.0.2 but cannot connect via ssh. On the VM, I can ping other windows host on my local network On the VM, I can't access to internet.

I suppose issue is on my Windows side while, as mentionned, I re-created the VM from scratch with an image that work properly.

Is there any setting, restriction, port access authorization on windows side I should check?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Fabrice

Comment: Your Host  ipconfig shows that you have installed the `Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network`. What did you choose for the network in the Virtualbox manager for that guest? Bridged/Host-Only/Nat....

Comment: I meant to set the NAT adapter. Should'nt I have this virtual adapter "host-only network" on my network configuration?

Comment: From the eth1 ip in the guest `10.0.3.15` I see this is a VirtualBox default Nat address range . To avoid additional layers I ever since used bridged. Would it be an option for you to at least temporarily switch to bridged?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed and was due to the ad-ware Web companion.
I just uninstall it and for the moment it solved the problem.
See here for more detail: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=82273